# My React/Redux website with React Router does not even respond on AWS(S3)

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-redux, react-router

I'm very new to React development and have a problem with deployment.

I'm suspecting react-router-dom after some researches, however, I can not figure out the problem.

I'm completely stuck in this problem for days.

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

### Problem

My React website does not even respond when it's deployed on AWS/S3. When I try to access the page, the alert saying 'Unresponsive Page' appears after a few minutes wait.

**Additional Info**
I realized that it also happens on the localhost. When I use command `yarn start`, the chrome browser displays my React website. When I try to access the same page on the localhost in other browsers, however, the page does not respond.

[image]

### What I have tried so far

- Add the `.htaccess` file in the /public/ directory as below.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

- Deploy another website without react-router-dom or redux to see if the problem lies with the way I deploy or not (It worked just fine)
- Deploy another website with redux (It worked just fine)
- Add `"homepage": "http://my-react-app-bucket-name.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com"` into package.json
- Add `"homepage": "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-react-app-bucket-name"` into package.json
- Comment out `<Switch></Switch>` including `<Route>` (It works just fine).

### What I'm using in the website

- create-react-app (for the creation of the app)
- React-router
- Redux
- Redux-thunk
- Redux-persist

### Suspicious part of the code

index.js

```
// Configure redux-persist
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers)

// Just to apply Redux DevTools
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

const store = createStore(persistedReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)))

const persistor = persistStore(store)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
)
```

App.js

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Router history={history}>
          <div>
            <Header onTermSubmit={this.onTermSubmit} />
            <div className="main-wrapper">
              <div className="ui container">
                <Switch>
                  <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                  <Route path="/detail/:id" component={Detail} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

history.js (Custom history for react-router)

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

export default createHistory()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set default index page in your S3 bucket? 
Also check in error log in console or try to access it in other browser.
Hope this will help.

[image]

After this Add Deploy to your Package file.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "deploy": "aws s3 sync build/ s3://wonderful-app",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

Comment: I have also tried this, however, it didn't work for me.

Comment: And I have also tried to visit the page in other browsers, however, it didn't work. It's taking forever to load the page, therefore, I can't even check the console log.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by myself.

The cause of everything was my silly mistake.

Inside of the mapStateToProps function, I had some logic other than connecting data in Redux Store with component's props.

I just forgot the rule that we don't put any logic inside of mapStateToProps...